# VueJS add class depending item v-for

Tags: ajax, for-loop, if-statement, vue.js, ternary

I would like make a table stripped green or red (boostrap).
Here is the context : I receive a list from an ajax call and here is the table row :

```
<tr v-for="item in items" class=getStyle(item)>
<td>{{item.line}}</td>
</tr>
```

My list of item is :

```
public class Wall
{
    public String Line{ get; set; }
    public BookRetrive Type { get; set; }
}
```

The value of Type is a Enum (Value == 0 / 1) when he is receive by the ajax call.
So if the item.type == 0, i would like to add the class "table-success" otherwise is would like to add the class "table-error".

```
computed: {
            getStyle(item) {
                return item.type === 0 ? "table-success" : "table-error";
            }
        }
```

But i can't get it, could you help me please.
Thank you

Comment: `computed` methods don't accept arguments, so you'll have to use a `method` instead.

Comment: Actually someone gave me an answer : 
<tr v-for="item in items" :class="{'table-success': item.type === 0, 'table-danger': item.type !== 0}">

Comment: That would work too. I prefer the `method` solution because it makes the template easier to read, and it's easier to update in the future.